# Calling two javascript functions with one button click gives a different result than with two

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webcam.js

So, I am currently using webcam.js in order to first capture a still of an image. Then, I have written some java script code to pass this to a hidden variable so I can grab it on the ASP.NET code behind so I can save it to the database. This is what my javascript code looks like:

```
<script src="webcam.js"></script>
<script>
    function transfer() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var dataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        var hf = document.getElementById('<%=hiddensquare.ClientID%>');
            hf.value = dataURL;

        }
</script>
<script>
    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap(function () {
        }, myCanvas);
    }
</script>
```

I am calling these with two html buttons that use their onclick event in order to call them, like this:

```
<input id="btnSnap" type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot();" />
<input id="btnTran" type="button" value="Transfer" onclick="transfer();" />
```

Just in case this has anything to with it, this is what my hidden variable looks like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddensquare" runat="server" Value="" />
```

I would like to call these two javascript functions with one button click, rather than two. However, when I try to do so, say, by simply putting in take_snapshot(); transfer(); in one of the button's onclick, or making a new javascript function that calls both of them, I always get a lot less data being passed into the hidden variable (I mean like much less than 1/10th) than if I have it done so I need to press two html buttons to allows to me to save.

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `Webcam.snap()` is asynchronous, so it's not necessarily complete when `transfer()` is executed.

Fortunately the first argument of snap is a callback function which will wait until snap is complete to execute, so you can simply pass `transfer` as the first argument to snap and you should achieve the results you're looking for:

```
function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap(transfer, myCanvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `take_snapshot(); transfer();` makes the `transfer()` code execute before the canvas has been updated with the image data.

`snap()` looks to be an async operation as it takes a callback function. You need to call your transfer function within that callback, or get the data uri as the passed argument to the callback.

> https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs#user-content-snapping-a-picture
>
> To snap a picture, just call the Webcam.snap() function, passing in a
>   callback function. **The image data will be passed to your function** as a
>   Data URI, which you can then display in your web page, or submit to a
>   server. Example:
>
> ```
> Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
>     document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
> } );
> ```

So in your case you would want to something like:

```
Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    data_uri = data_uri.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    var hf = document.getElementById('<%=hiddensquare.ClientID%>');
    hf.value = data_uri;
},myCanvas);

//or 
function transfer(data_uri) {
    data_uri = data_uri.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    var hf = document.getElementById('<%=hiddensquare.ClientID%>');
    hf.value = data_uri;
}
Webcam.snap(transfer,myCanvas);
```